# Is there any way to control Raspberry Pi GPIO pins without Webiopi?

Tags: gpio, python, pi-gpio

I want to control my Raspberry Pi GPIO pins over internet, but as I searched for answers I found Webiopi. I don't like Webiopi, so I am searching for any other way to control the pins with Python. Thank you!

Comment: What about [Rpi.GPIO](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RPi.GPIO)? There are tons of tutorials. Here a [tutorial from sparkfun](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/raspberry-gpio)

Comment: How to control GPIO over internet with Rpi.GPIO, any tutorial? @MadMike

Comment: @M.Simel You *could* write your own script that suits your requirements. I recommend Node.JS or PHP. You can interact with the system (including GPIO) using those languages.

Comment: You could make a little webserver with cherrypy and control rpi.gpio from there. Here the first english tutorial I've found from Google: [Controlling LED from CherryPy Web App](https://raspberrypiwonderland.wordpress.com/2014/03/14/controlling-led-from-cherrypy-web-app/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recent GPIO Zero release (1.4) includes several new chapters on remote GPIO:

- [Configuring Remote GPIO](http://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/remote_gpio.html)
- [Remote GPIO Recipes](http://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes_remote_gpio.html)

I should add that this is achieved via Joan's excellent pigpio package, mentioned in the other answer (GPIO Zero is just configured to use pigpio as its pin driver instead of the current default of RPi.GPIO).

Answer (score 3):

pigpio has a [Python module](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html) which can control the GPIO of a networked Pi from a Windows, Mac, or Linux PC.

Comment: What is the name of module and how can I use it?

Comment: @M.Simel All the information you need is in the linked page(s).